# Modifying html element created in jQuery recursively, inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**Problem:** I'm trying to modify an HTML table I created inside a function in JS (jQuery) looping through rows and columns and setting a value with .html().

**Code:**

So I have the html element I created in JS

```
var html = $("<table id='table_art'><tbody><tr><th></th><th>2013-01-01</th><th>2013-02-01</th></tr><tr><th>DATA123</th><td>2,2</td><td>3,2</td></tr><tr></tbody></table>");
```

Then the data I use to populate the table

```
var data = {
  "fechas": ["2013-01-01", "2013-02-01"],
  "dataval": {
    "2013-01-01": {
      "DATA123": 98.93
    },
    "2013-02-01": {
      "DATA123": 98.12
    }
  },
  "names": ["DATA123"]
};
```

I loop through the data, get the desired value and set it where it should be set. I do this by selecting the desired position in the table using the selectors.

```
var fechas = data.fechas;
var nombres = data.names;

var val = "";
var posR = 0;
var posC = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < fechas.length; i++) {

   for (var j = 0; j < nombres.length; j++) {

        $("#table_art > tbody > tr").eq(j + 1).children("td").eq(i).html(val);
            }
    }
```

I get the html as string just to check if my values have been updated just to find they have not.

```
console.log(html.html());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8uk11rn/4/)

**Desired result:**

Wrapped by table or just tbody, it doesn't really matter as long as I get the rows and columns correctly populated

```
 <table id="table_art">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>2013-01-01</th>
            <th>2013-02-01</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>DATA123</th>
            <td>98.93</td>
            <td>98.12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Might I suggest that you simplify your problem? Reduce the amount of data with which to populate the table, create a smaller table and reduce the amount of CSS in that string of HTML to make it easier to visualise what you're doing, what you're doing wrong and what we need to do to try and help. Think "[MCVE]."

Comment: Yes, will do right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8uk11rn/7/)

here's what's wrong with your code :

- the table wasn't even created to be populated ..... by creating
  `<body>` tag and insert the provided html in it the problem is
  solved.
- the variable `html` is supposed to be just a string       containing
  the html you want not `$("<table etc...>");`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I can't use an external html, not even body tags.

Comment: well I don't know why that might be .. but check this js fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/a8uk11rn/12/    it'll append the table to `<html>` tags

Answer (score 0):

```
var dates = data.fechas;
var names = data.names;

var table = $("<table>");

// Create row from data array, each index is one cell
// if isTop is true, all cells will be created as headers (th)
var createRow = function(data, isTop) {
    var row = $("<tr>");
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var cell = $( isTop === true || i === 0 ? "<th>" : "<td>");
        cell.text(data[i]);
        row.append(cell);
    }

    return row;
}

// Create temporary array with blank value and dates values
// and then create a header row
var tempDates = [""];
Array.prototype.push.apply(tempDates, dates)
table.append( createRow(tempDates, true) );

// Create data rows
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var rowData = [names[i]];
    for(var j = 0; j < dates.length; j++ )
       rowData.push(data.dataval[dates[j]][names[i]]);

    table.append( createRow(rowData));
}

$("body").append(table);
```

[Here is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/jmqdxupe/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using inner loops. Your requirement is pretty straight forward and can be achieved by using `map` and `filter` function:

First get the an object which maps `fechas` to the values in `dataval`

something like

```
var fechas = data.fechas;
var dataval = data.dataval;


feacha_seperate = fechas.map(function(val) {dataval[val].fechas = val;
return dataval[val]
})
```

Then you can use `map` functions to apply whatever `html` tags to the data: something like:

```
var html = $("<table class='table table-bordered' id='tabla_servicios' style='width:100%; padding:12px'><tbody><tr><th></th><th>2013-01-01</th><th>2013-02-01</th><th>2013-03-01</th><th>2013-04-01</th><th>2013-05-01</th><th>2013-06-01</th><th>2013-07-01</th><th>2013-08-01</th></tr><tr><th>INICIA.ADIF.ES</th><td>2,2</td><td>3,2</td><td>4,2</td><td>5,2</td><td>6,2</td><td>7,2</td><td>8,2</td><td>9,2</td></tr><tr><th>SALIDA INTERNET</th><td>2,3</td><td>3,3</td><td>4,3</td><td>5,3</td><td>6,3</td><td>7,3</td><td>8,3</td><td>9,3</td></tr><tr><th>SALIDA INTRANET</th><td>2,4</td><td>3,4</td><td>4,4</td><td>5,4</td><td>6,4</td><td>7,4</td><td>8,4</td><td>9,4</td></tr><tr><th>SERVICIO DE CORREO</th><td>2,5</td><td>3,5</td><td>4,5</td><td>5,5</td><td>6,5</td><td>7,5</td><td>8,5</td><td>9,5</td></tr><tr><th>WWW.ADIF.ES</th><td>2,6</td><td>3,6</td><td>4,6</td><td>5,6</td><td>6,6</td><td>7,6</td><td>8,6</td><td>9,6</td></tr></tbody></table>");

var data = {"fechas":["2013-01-01","2013-02-01","2013-03-01","2013-04-01","2013-05-01","2013-06-01","2013-07-01","2013-08-01"],"dataval":{"2013-06-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":98.58,"WWW.ADIF.ES":100,"SALIDA INTRANET":99.2,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":98.9},"2013-05-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":96.72,"WWW.ADIF.ES":99.9,"SALIDA INTRANET":99.76,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":99.91},"2013-03-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":97.07,"WWW.ADIF.ES":99.99,"SALIDA INTRANET":99.9,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":99.87},"2013-07-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":99.48,"WWW.ADIF.ES":99.88,"SALIDA INTRANET":99.87,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":99.74},"2013-01-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":98.93,"WWW.ADIF.ES":99.3,"SALIDA INTRANET":98.82,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":100},"2013-04-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":96.65,"WWW.ADIF.ES":99.83,"SALIDA INTRANET":99.3,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":99.98},"2013-02-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":98.12,"WWW.ADIF.ES":99.95,"SALIDA INTRANET":99.75,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":100},"2013-08-01":{"SALIDA INTERNET":100,"INICIA.ADIF.ES":99.43,"WWW.ADIF.ES":100,"SALIDA INTRANET":99.9,"SERVICIO DE CORREO":100}},"names":["INICIA.ADIF.ES","SALIDA INTERNET","SALIDA INTRANET","SERVICIO DE CORREO","WWW.ADIF.ES"]};

var fechas = data.fechas;
var dataval = data.dataval;


feacha_seperate = fechas.map(function(val) {dataval[val].fechas = val;
return dataval[val]
})

fechas_th = feacha_seperate.map(function(val) {
return '<th>'+val.fechas+'</th>'
})

INICIA_ADIF_ES_td = feacha_seperate.map(function(val) {
return '<td>'+val['INICIA.ADIF.ES']+'</td>'
})

SALIDA_INTERNET_td = feacha_seperate.map(function(val) {
return '<td>'+val['SALIDA INTERNET']+'</td>'
})

SALIDA_INTRANET_td = feacha_seperate.map(function(val) {
return '<td>'+val['SALIDA INTRANET']+'</td>'
})

SERVICIO_DE_CORREO_td = feacha_seperate.map(function(val) {
return '<td>'+val['SERVICIO DE CORREO']+'</td>'
})

WWW_ADIF_ES_td = feacha_seperate.map(function(val) {
return '<td>'+val['WWW.ADIF.ES']+'</td>'
})

whole_html = '<tr><th></th>'+fechas_th+'</tr><tr>'+INICIA_ADIF_ES_td+'</tr><tr>'+SALIDA_INTERNET_td+'</tr><tr>'+SERVICIO_DE_CORREO_td+'</tr><tr>'+WWW_ADIF_ES_td+'</tr>'

console.log(whole_html);
```

**P.S** the above method can be refactored further to suit your needs

**EDIT** if your `html` depend on `names` attribute of data you can do comething like:

```
var fechas = data.fechas;
var dataval = data.dataval;
var names = data.names;

feacha_seperate = fechas.map(function(val) {
return dataval[val]
})

//here the val refers to the names array if you want to change them to have custom names 
//create a separate array like var my_new_names=['test','test1'] in the exact order of the names array..
//then in the below code instead of `'<tr><th>'+val+'</th>'` do `'<tr><th>'+my_new_names[key]+'</th>'`
get_names_as_seperate_arrays= names.map(function(val,key) {
   return '<tr><th>'+val+'</th>'+feacha_seperate.map(function(val1) {
        return '<td>'+val1[val]+'</td>'
   })+'</tr>'
})

fechas_th = feacha_seperate.map(function(val) {
    return '<th>'+val.fechas+'</th>'
})
whole_html =  '<tr><th></th>'+fechas_th+'</tr>'+get_names_as_seperate_arrays.join('');
console.log(whole_html);
```

`get_names_as_seperate_arrays` will have `td` data depending on `names` attribute

Comment: Can I ask you to edit your answer with different data names, please?

Comment: just do a `map` function between the original `names` array and your required names array refer to the comments in edit answer